# Python bitstring uint seen as long

Tags: python, uint

I have the following:

I read 30 bits from a bitstream:

```
MMSI = b.readlist('uint:30')
```

This seems to work normally except when the values get higher.

```
MMSI = b.readlist('uint:30')
p = 972128254
# repr(MMSI)[:-1]
print p
print "MMSI :"
print MMSI
if MMSI == p:
```

The code above outputs:

```
972128254
MMSI :
[972128254L]
```

The whole if MMSI ==p: is skipped for it is not equal for some reason.
I do not understand why the value that is far lower than max.int:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.maxint
2147483647
```

I do not understand why I get a Long returned and not a uint?
If the value returned is 244123456 it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`2147483647` is maxint, but an int is 32 bits and you're using 30 bits.  So your max is 1/4 of that, or about 500 million.

Answer (score 1):

Values will be 'long' if an intermediate value was a long. So for example `2**1000 / 2**999` will equal `2L`. This is just to do with the internals of the method you called and shouldn't affect most code.

The real problem is the comparison you have in your code is comparing an int to a list, which is not what you want to do. You can either use the `read` method rather than `readlist` to return a single item, or take the first element of the returned list: `if MMSI[0] == p:`

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I figured that if I read 30bits and returned it as uint value it would automatically be a 32bits value. 
So what you are saying is that I would have to add leading zeros to make a 32 bit value and then it should work. 
So that is what I have tested and now I am lost.

I figured lets encode the value I want to compare to in the same way. So this is what I did:

```
  from bitarray import bitarray
  from bitstring import BitArray, BitStream,pack
  from time import sleep
  import string

  MMSI = b.readlist('uint:30')
  x = pack('uint:30',972000000)
  p = x.readlist('uint:30')
  y = pack('uint:30',972999999)
  q = y.read('uint:30')
  print p
  print q
  print x
  print y
  print MMSI
```

resulting in:

```
 p = [972000000L]
 q = 972999999
 x = 0b111001111011111000101100000000
 y = 0b111001111111101100110100111111
 MMSI = [972128254L]
```

How can it be that the higher value 972999999 is not a long?